# How do I count multifield for body of block?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

So I have a custom template for the custom block and I can print each one using the following code.

```
Body 1: {{content.body.0}}
Body 2: {{content.body.1}}
```

I need to know how many there are. I tried a whole bunch of variations of `{{ content.body | length }}` or `{{ content.body.getvalue | length }}` but nothing is working.

My goal is to add responsive grid support depending on how many bodies there are. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your block.html.twig template:

```
 {{ content.body['#items'].getvalue|length }}
```

Although to access the individual items, it may be better to create a field template such as 
field--node--body.html.twig

then you can do

```
{{ items|length }}
```

in that template.

Comment: I tried `{{ content.body['#items']|length }}` however nothing displayed.

Comment: This 
`{{ content.body | length }}`
displays 18, which is wrong, it should be 2 as there is only 2 bodies.  

Not sure what you mean by creating the field template, what would I change from the default?

Comment: This is a good idea to count in `#items`. But you need to use `.getvalue` to extract the field array from it. `{{ content.body['#items'].getvalue|length }}`

Comment: @4k4 `{{ content.body['#items'].getvalue|length }}` displays nothing for me in my custom block template.

Comment: @ToddKruger Just tested the code in `block.html.twig`. It works.

Comment: Updated the answer based on @4k4's comment.

Comment: Thanks All, @4k4, when trying in block.html.twig it worked so I must of messed up on my custom twig template.